# Рекурсивный SQL запрос, или как сделать несколько выборок одновременно

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой задачей:
в таблице БД, дерево каталога хранится таком виде (привычный для всех формат хранения дерева каталога):

```
id  +   pid   +   name
-----------------------
1   +   0     +   Каталог
2   +   1     +   Книга 1
3   +   1     +   Книга 2
4   +   3     +   Глава 1
5   +   3     +   Глава 2
6   +   3     +   Глава 3
```

Далее задан путь в виде массива, и требуется найти этот раздел в таблице, если такой существует.

Путь задан массивом названий разделов, в таком виде:

```
// Вложенность разделов может быть любой
$path = ["Раздел 1", "Подраздел", "Подраздел подраздела"];
```

Нужно вывести из таблицы строку, которая соответствует названию `"Подраздел подраздела"`. Т.к. в  таблице может быть несколько записей с таким название,  нужно проверять, что этот раздел находится по такому адресу:

**"Раздел 1"** => **"Подраздел"** => **"Подраздел подраздела"**.

Путь всегда задан от корня.

Насколько я понял, нужно с начало найти "Раздел 1" у которого `pid` (parent id) = 0, получить его `id`, дальше найти **"Подраздел"** для которого `pid` будет равен найденному в предыдущем запросе `id` и т.д.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли такое решить на чистом SQL ? Чтобы не делать по несколько запросов ?

Comment: *Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли такое решить на чистом SQL ?* Если диалект поддерживает рекурсивные CTE - легко. Строим полные пути узлов, конвертируем в тот же формат исходные данные, и выводим запись, где совпадает (если найдётся, конечно).

Comment: @Akina а mysql такое может?

Comment: Только восьмая версия.

Comment: @Akina а других решений с версией 5.7  нету? Только с помощью php делать несколько запросов в подряд?

Comment: Хранимая процедура прекрасно справится с задачей.

Comment: Я так вижу у вас количество уровней вложенности всегда фиксировано, а если так, то это облегчает задачу для MYSQL. Вы можете добавить столбец lvl - у вас их будет 3 и цеплять сперва 3 уровень, потом 2 потом 1

Answer (score 0):

По-видимому, ваша таблица будет выглядеть примерно так:

```sql
CREATE TABLE library
( 
    id  int, 
    pid int, 
    name  VARCHAR(200)  
); 

INSERT 
  INTO library 
    (id, pid, name) 
  VALUES 
    (1,0,'Каталог'),
    (2,1,'Книга 1'),
    (3,1,'Книга 2'),
    (4,2,'Глава 1'),
    (5,2,'Глава 2'),
    (6,3,'Глава 1'),
    (7,3,'Глава 2'),
    (8,3,'Глава 3');
```

Тогда описаный вами запрос будет иметь вид:

```sql
SELECT * FROM library 
  LEFT JOIN 
     library AS book 
       ON book.pid = library.id  AND book.name = 'Книга 1'
    LEFT JOIN 
      library AS book_part 
        ON book_part.pid = book.id  AND book_part.name = 'Глава 1'
```

Рабочий пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304d41/1/0)

Стоит учитывать, что вам, скорее всего, не нужны все поля получившегося запроса